# Rewriting this angle using only $\theta$, $r$ and $l$.

Tags: geometry

This is the diagram:

[image: angles]

If I have the lengths $r$ and $l$ and also the angle $\theta$.
How can I calculate $\theta'$ in a way that it doesn't contain anything expect $\theta$, $r$ and $l$ ?

As you see I have written my own approach. But it contains $\beta$ which is unknown. and I could find a way to express $\beta$ using those three allowed items. help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the side in the obtuse triangle opposite the angle $90+\theta$

Applying the cosine rule gives $$x^2=r^2+l^2-2rl\cos(90+\theta)=r^2+l^2+2rl\sin\theta$$

Applying the sine rule gives$$\frac{\sin\alpha}{l}=\frac{\sin(90+\theta)}{x}$$

Hence $$\cos\theta'=\frac{l\cos\theta}{\sqrt{r^2+l^2+2rl\sin\theta}}$$